# After moving an element in jquery sortable, I would like to move that element left by 30 pixels

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

My setup is three divs using jquery sortable in a vertically sortable list.  When I drag an element to a new position, I would like that element to shift 30 pixels left, so that it is visibly offset from the rest of the elements.  It should remain a part of the sortable list.  I have tried the position option option on the update method, but it doesn't seem to work.

HTML:

```
<div class="sortable">
    <div id="1">1</div>
    <div id="2">2</div>
    <div id="3">3</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
        $(".sortable").sortable({
            update: function (event, ui) {
                placeholder: 'placeholder';
                position: {0,-30};
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I would advise doing this with CSS.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/sxLfpwf8/

**HTML**

```
<div class="sortable">
  <div id="1">1</div>
  <div id="2">2</div>
  <div id="3">3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.indent {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $(".sortable").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
      ui.item.addClass("indent");
    }
  });
});
```

If you're unable to do this or cannot modify the CSS, you can do it via jQuery with direct styling.

```
$(function() {
  $(".sortable").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
      ui.item.css("padding-left", "30px");
    }
  });
});
```

Using Padding will move the content of the div over 30 pixels from the left border. If you want to move the `DIV`, use `margin-left`.